# Crystal Report Excel Export Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I created a Windows Form Application using C# that have a few Crystal Reports. Whenever I try to export the crystal report in Excel using the Crystal Report Export build in button, the excel formatting output is completely different. My Subtotal and Grand Total does not align with the corresponding column. Any idea what I can do to fix it or is it a flaw in crystal report exporting coding?

Comment: Did you check http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/231 and http://www.kenhamady.com/news0506.shtml ? they might be useful (from link only answer)

Answer (score 1):

When exporting to excel, there are several reasons that can cause formatting issue. For example, If you go to Export options Using the column width of Header 1 may give you better formatting that the whole page. The best way to avoid formatting problems when exporting to excel is designing your report around the fact that it will be exported to excel. That means try to keep the fields in every section aligned. so if you have two .5 in fields in one section. and you have another field in the section below it. Make that field .5 or 1 in and align it with the fields above it. Also make sure all the sections are fitted by right clicking a section and click fit to section. If your still getting unwanted black rows when exporting,

1.)Right click section 2.)click arrange lines 3.)right click section 4.)click fitSection

Answer (score 0):

you should have provided the screenshot of your report.... but will try to answer to the extent I understand.

This is not a flaw in crystal report...normally detail fields have extra columns compared to grand totals or group summaries so the wayout would be to insert `dummy text fields` before the sub totals and grand totals so that those are alligned correctly.

If this is not your requirement post a screenshot of how the report looks like and how do you need the output